# Strongly Connected component algorithm implementation(Python)

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

My goal is to implement Strongly Connected Components algorithm using python.
I have splitted up my code on 3 parts:

1. Data Load:

   ```
   import csv as csv
   import numpy as np
   import random as random
   import copy as copy
   import math
   import sys, threading
   import time
   sys.setrecursionlimit(800000)
   threading.stack_size(67108864)

   start = time.time()

   num_nodes = 160000
   graph = [[] for i in range(num_nodes)]
   reverse_graph = [[] for i in range(num_nodes)]
   graph_2_step = [[] for i in range(num_nodes)]

   file = open("C:\\Users\\yefida\\Desktop\\Study_folder\\Online_Courses\\Algorithms\\Project 5\\test7.txt", "r") 
   data = file.readlines()
   for line in data:
       if line.strip():
           items = line.split()  
           if int(items[1]) not in reverse_graph[int(items[1]) - 1]:   
               reverse_graph[int(items[1]) - 1].append(int(items[1])) 
               reverse_graph[int(items[1]) - 1].append(int(items[0])) 
           else:
               reverse_graph[int(items[1]) - 1].append(int(items[0])) 



           if int(items[0]) not in graph[int(items[0]) - 1]:   
               graph[int(items[0]) - 1].append(int(items[0])) 
               graph[int(items[0]) - 1].append(int(items[1])) 
           else:
               graph[int(items[0]) - 1].append(int(items[1])) 


   for i in range(len(graph)):
       if len(graph[i]) == 0:
           graph[i] = [i+1,i+1]
       if len(reverse_graph[i]) == 0:
           reverse_graph[i] = [i+1,i+1]


   end = time.time()
   time_taken = end - start
   print('Time: ',time_taken)
   ```
2. Depth-first search algorithm on the reversed graph:

   ```
   #2. Run DFS-loop on reversed Graph:
   start = time.time()

   t = 0 # for finishing lines: how many nodes are processed so far
   s = None # current source vertex
   explored = set()
   finish_time = {} 


   def DFS(graph,node):
       explored.add(node)
       global s

       for vertex in graph[node - 1][1:]:
           if vertex not in explored:
               DFS(graph,vertex)    

       global t
       t+= 1
       finish_time[node] = t

   #Nodes starts from n to 1
   for i in range(max(reverse_graph)[0],0,-1):
       if i not in explored:
           s = i
           DFS(reverse_graph,i)

   #Mapping to the new list in increasing order
   for edge in range(len(graph)):
       for vertex in range(len(graph[edge])):
           graph[edge][vertex] = finish_time[graph[edge][vertex]]

       graph_2_step[graph[edge][0] - 1] = graph[edge]



   end = time.time()
   time_taken = end - start
   print('Time: ',time_taken)
   ```
3. Depth-first-search algortihm on the graph after step 2:

   ```
     #3. Run DFS-loop on Graph with original directions(but with labeled finishing times):
   all_components = []#Saves all strongly connected components
   all_comp_elem = set()#check if element is in Strongly Connected Components(already explored)
   SSC = set() # strongly connected component, that will be saved in "all_components"
   explored= set()  # variables, that are already explored 
   next_elem = 0 # contains information how many elements have to be checked, before making a decision 
   #c)modification of DFS
   def DFS_2_Path(graph,node):
       global all_components 
       global SSC 
       global next_elem 
       explored.add(node) #node is explored

       next_elem += len(graph[node - 1][1:]) # add number elements, that must be explored from the current node
       #checking one vertex -> minus one element that must be explored
       for vertex in graph[node - 1][1:]:
           next_elem -= 1
           #check if element is in Strongly Connected Components(already explored)
           if node not in all_comp_elem:
               SSC.add(node)

           #if vertex is not explored, than reccursion and go to the next vertex
           if vertex not in explored:

               SSC.add(vertex)
               DFS_2_Path(graph,vertex)



           #if vertex is not the last element in the chain(Ex: [6,5,1,7] -> 6 is a main Node, and 7 is the last element, to which
           #node 6 is connected)    
           elif vertex in explored and vertex != graph[node - 1][1:][len(graph[node - 1][1:]) - 1]:
               continue
            #if vertex is the last element in the chain(Ex: [6,5,1,7] -> 6 is a main Node, and 7 is the last element, to which
               #node 6 is connected) -> update stringly connected components   
           elif vertex in explored and vertex == graph[node - 1][1:][len(graph[node - 1][1:]) - 1] and next_elem == 0:
               all_components.append(SSC)
               all_comp_elem.update(SSC)
               SSC = set()

   #Main loop             
   for i in range(max(graph_2_step)[0],0,-1):
       if i not in explored:
            DFS_2_Path(graph_2_step,i)



   end = time.time()
   time_taken = end - start
   print('Time: ',time_taken)
   ```

I have tested my algorithm on different test cases -> it works correct.
First two parts of the algorithm work fast(on the data set with 160000 nodes).
But when I run the third part -> kernel in Jupyter dies.

I have improved the speed of the code as much as I could. I definitely need a fresh look on my code.

P.S Don't look at first 2 parts of the code. I provided them to you only for the test, if you want to test.

P.S.S The link to the file, that I have used for the test: https://github.com/beaunus/stanford-algs/blob/master/testCases/course2/assignment1SCC/input_mostlyCycles_64_160000.txt

Comment: Have you had a look at the [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) library and especially its [strongly_connected_components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected_components) function? Not that I wanted to discourage you from trying it yourself, but depending on your needs that could make it a lot easier.

Comment: What do you mean with reversed graph?

Comment: @dfhwze By reversed graph I meant, that we reverse all of the arcs in our original graph

Comment: @AlexV I know, that special library exists. I am coding this algorithm in order to improve my skills in Python and to understand algorithms better :)